# Spice for graphic, pulseaudio for sound

Tags: kvm, qemu, alsa, libvirt, spice

When we use Spice in a virtual machine under KVM/qemu/libvirt, the QEMU_AUDIO_DRV is set to spice by default.
My host (debian-Stretch) use a good sound card (Xonar DX) and a better sound driver (pulseaudio,alsa).
How to use in a virtual machine spice for the graphic aspect and pulseaudio or alsa for the sound aspect (whatever the guest OS) ?

**Note 1**: in the domain.xml, I added:

```
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_DRV' value='pa'/>
  <qemu:env name='QEMU_PA_SERVER' value='/run/user/1000/pulse/native'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

Now, in domain.log, I see:

```
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa QEMU_PA_SERVER=/run/user/1000/pulse/native
```

Well but I don't know if my guest uses pulseaudio or not because domain.xml has the following section:

```
<sound model='ich6'>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
</sound>
```

**Note 2**: other try:

```
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_DRV' value='alsa'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

No sound.

Answer (score 1):

PulseAudio normally accepts only a connection from one user. To mitigate this you could either

1. run QEMU as user 1000 - [Edit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libvirt#PulseAudio) `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` and add/change `user = "<user>"` or
2. allow PulseAudio to [accept anonymous connections](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Allowing_multiple_users_to_use_PulseAudio_at_the_same_time).

Comment: My solution works for pulseaudio (with the 1000 user) but not with alsa. Shall I also remove the ich6 section ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `qemu:commandline` snippet is alright, I used it to nicely direct guest's sound to specific PA sound card on the host. Here is the Volume Control dialog entry on the host:
[image: Volume Control dialog]
To get connected to current user PA just create your domain under `qemu:///session`, which means the VM process runs under current user ID by default. No need to change global QEMU or PA configs. To debug headless you can see if PA gets connection from virt-manager with `pacmd list-clients`:

```
index: 137
driver: <protocol-native.c>
owner module: 11
properties:
    application.name = "virt-manager"
    native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
    native-protocol.version = "34"
    application.process.id = "97515"
    application.process.user = "xyz"
    application.process.host = "xyz"
    application.process.binary = "python3.9"
    application.icon_name = "virt-manager"
    application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
    window.x11.display = ":0.0"
    application.process.machine_id = "68058b3d029948a1ae03d28f827a6f53"
    application.process.session_id = "c2"
```